# Firebase: return all collection items that have an id in an array in order to do an `onSnapshot`

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This should be a simple query, but I can't seem to get it to work or find how to get it done.

I have a list of accepted ids of a certain collection in an array. I want to do a `get` each item of that collection that matches one of those ids. Kind of like the reverse of the commonly used `array-contains`. For example:

```
const acceptableIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']

const myCollectionDispose = await db
    .collection('myCollection')
    .where('id', 'is-in-array', acceptableIds)
    .onSnapshot(doSomething)
```

I know I could just do a map on the `acceptableIds` with a `Promise.all` to fetch them but for this particular case I need a to also set `onSnapshot` at the end of it (as you can see in the example code), so that won't do.

Anyway, what would be the best way to do this?

It could be either to be able to fetch the items of `myCollection` by id using the where or being able to set `onSnapshot` on the array generated from the `Promise.all`. Just in case the latter one is relevant, here is the code for that:

```
const acceptableIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']

const myCollectionDispose = await Promise.all(
  acceptableIds.map(id => {
    return db
      .collection('myCollection')
      .doc(id)
      .onSnapshot(doSomething)
  })
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save each of the Promises in an array and then use a Promise.all() when each is complete.

```
const acceptableIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
const promises = []

for (var i = 0; i < acceptableIds.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
        db.collection('myCollection')
        .where('id', 'array-contains', acceptableIds[i])
        .onSnapshot( /* Do Something */ )
    )
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
     // Whatever you need to do next with all the snapshots (e.x. remove them all)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still won't work. For all intents and purposes this is still the same thing as my solution using the `.map` inside a `Promise.all`. Once I get the entries, I still need to do a `.onSnapshot` of my result (that is all the entries I have)

Comment: The whole purpose of this is that I want to show those specific items of `myCollection` on a screen and update them as necessary.

Comment: I just updated the answer. I ran a quick test in one of my applications and was able to run multiple listeners through a for loop and save them to an array. I had it `console.log()` the snapshot data to make sure it was still registering and it was. Let me know if this works for you too,

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"

db.collection('myCollection')
.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", yourArrayOfIds)
```

Here, `yourArrayOfIds` can be up to 10 items. You will have to implement required batch logic to gather up your result, if necessary.